# How to make Twitter Bootstrap Collapse work on dynamically loaded html using ajax

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am loading html using **ajax** call, this html has **Bootstrap Collapse**. The issue is **Collapse is not working**, if you click it will expand but it won't collapse again.

To check if I am doing something wrong, I put the same code on a static page (not loaded using ajax) and it works fine. So its seems issue only with dynamically loaded html.

I tried manually enabling Collapse using

```
$(".collapse").collapse()
```

but still same issue.

I guess I need to use jquery's `live() / on()` methods, because the html is dynamic, but not sure how do I do that for calling `$(".collapse").collapse()` because I think it only works on events or is it something else that I need to do ?

Comment: why don't you call `$(".collapse").collapse()` inside the ajax's success fnction after the dynamic html is appended..

Comment: Collapse seems to work with content loaded by an ajax request. I made a simple jsfiddle test: http://jsfiddle.net/QVsse/3/ . If it for some reason does not work, I suggest you look into bipens advice and call the collapse() in the callback function of your ajax call.

Comment: @bipen I could not have thought of that. Also I found other way $(".res").html(data).collapse(); I will give try to both & update. Thanks

Comment: ok sure... let me know..if any problem.. :)

Comment: @Leif I checked jsfiddle, it seems that it works with jquery 1.7.2 onwards. I need to check my jquery version.

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13910596/how-to-make-twitter-bootstrap-collapse-work-on-dynamically-loaded-html-using-aja

Answer (score 8, accepted):

i would suggest you to  call

```
 $(".collapse").collapse()
```

inside the ajax's success function after the dynamic html is appended.

Answer (score 4):

My solve is:

```
    $('.collapse').on('show', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.attr('data-href'))
    {
        $this.html($.getJSON($this.attr('data-href'),function(data){
            $this.html(data.html);
            $this.removeAttr('style');
        }));
    }
    })
```

Comment: I tried the same as you mentioned above, I am not able to get it work. It expanded properly but then click again, it doesnt collapse in firefox. Can you help me in resolving it?

Answer (score 1):

Just execute this on ajax success event.

```
$('[data-toggle="collapse"]').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var target_element= $(this).attr("href");
      $(target_element).collapse('toggle');
      return false;
});
```