# Bootstrap collapse stops working when switching field type to WYSIWYG

Tags: wordpress, bootstrap-4, advanced-custom-fields

I'm creating a FAQ page on my wordpress site. I am using bootstrap 4.0's collapse component and ACF Pro to build the page.

On the back end, an admin can add questions and answers. The answers are to be hidden on the front end until a user clicks on the question to toggle the answer. Originally the answer field was a text area. All was working great! But when I changed the answer field type to be a WYSIWYG editor, the collapse functionality stopped working altoghether and the answers are not hidden or collapsible. Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance, code snippet below.

```
         <?php while( have_rows('topic_information') ): the_row(); 
          $question = get_sub_field('question');
          $answer = get_sub_field('answer'); 
          $counter++;
          ?>
            <div class="question-btn collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#<?php echo $counter; ?>" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="<?php echo $counter; ?>">
              <div class="question">
                  <p class="question-text">
                  <?php echo $question; ?>
                  </p>
                  <div class="toggle-status"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="answer">  
                  <p id="<?php echo $counter; ?>" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion"><?php echo $answer; ?>
                  </p>
              </div> <!--.answer-->
            </div> <!--.question-btn-->

        <?php endwhile; ?> <!-- WHILE ( have_rows('topic_information') -->
```

Comment: what WYSIWYG plugin are you using?

Comment: I'm using advanced custom fields pro @johnnyarguelles

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced this with bootstrap when the bootstrap.js, bootstrapcdn or bootstrap.min.js is referenced more than once on a page.   For me the plugin I was using was also importing or referencing its own bootstrap.js or bootstrap.min.js file which it why it was happening to me.

I would try removing the bootstrap.js or bootstrap.min.js reference from the ACF Pro plugin if possible or try removing it from your project (since your plugin is already referencing it) to see if works.

If that doesn't work you might want to try doing it from javascript since it sounds like the faq is dynamically generated:

[bootstrap collapse not working when creating dyanmically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26421401/bootstrap-collapse-not-working-when-creating-dyanmically)

Good luck